# Best method of importing scapy

Tags: python, python-import, scapy

I've used: from scapy.all import *
in the past however now I am getting conflicts (Queue) within the namespace.

Whats the best method to import scapy? Methods I've looked into:

```
import scapy
import scapy.all
from scapy import all
```

Comment: Try to use from...import

Comment: if you import like `from scapy import all`, then you will override the built in [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often use, when I do not want to overwrite my namespace:

```
from scapy import all as scapy
```

After that everything is accessible under `scapy.`:

```
scapy.send(scapy.IP()/scapy.ICMP())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from scapy.all import sr1,IP,ICMP
```

Is probably the best way of doing this.

To import all the layers at once (to test packets against them) use:

```
from scapy.layers import all
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from scapy.all import srp,Ether,ARP,conf,send,arping
```